# Alternative to AppAuth?

Tags: android, oauth, appauth

I want to integrate OAuth2 / OpenID Connect in my app. I intended to use [`AppAuth`](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) for that, but it seems to have a potentially [missing maintainer](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/444). What alternatives are there?

Comment: The project was recently handed off to two new maintainers. I suspect it's too early to tell if the health of AppAuth will be maintained, but with the number of large players who use AppAuth, it'd surprise me if the project tied.